# How to convert unicode \ud83e\udd36 to &#129334 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, unicode

I would like to convert

```
\ud83e\udd36
```

to

```
&#129334
```

In this page  they are able to convert it
[charbase.com](https://www.charbase.com/1f936-unicode-invalid-character)

Is this doable using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`codePointAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt):

```js
let str = "\ud83e\udd36";

console.log('&#' + str.codePointAt(0) + ';');
```

Comment: Whats the representation of zero in codePointAt(0)?

Comment: @Vlad Did you follow the link? It says "*`pos` - Position of an element in the String to return the code point value from.*"

Comment: To answer my question. zero is Position of an element in the String to return the code point value from. I missed that. Thanks